# How can I redirect to another View using if-else inside Controller class in Spring Boot? For example :

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller

Here, i have Controller class with function name validLogin which returns model and view. I passed two parameters through login form and and find out if these are exist in my database or not. My question now is if the parameters are not present in my database, how can I redirect to another view inside else{} block?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/validLogin")
    public ModelAndView validLogin(@RequestParam(name = "email", defaultValue = "retryEmail") String email,
            @RequestParam(name = "password", defaultValue = "retryPass") String password) {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
        RegisteredUsers s1=docDao.findByEmailAndPassword(email,password);
        mv.addObject("email",email);
        mv.addObject("password",password);
        mv.addObject(s1);
        mv.setViewName("validLogin.jsp");
        System.out.println("email id: " + email+" password : " + password);
        if(s1 != null) {
            System.out.println("Value exists..");
        }else {

        }
        return mv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You need to have an error page to be your target when something goes wrong

```
  @RequestMapping(path = "/validLogin")
        public ModelAndView validLogin(@RequestParam(name = "email", defaultValue = "retryEmail") String email,
                @RequestParam(name = "password", defaultValue = "retryPass") String password) {
            ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
            RegisteredUsers s1=docDao.findByEmailAndPassword(email,password);
            mv.addObject("email",email);
            mv.addObject("password",password);
            mv.addObject(s1);
            mv.setViewName("validLogin.jsp");
            System.out.println("email id: " + email+" password : " + password);
            if(s1 != null) {
                System.out.println("Value exists..");
            return mv;
            }else {
            return new ModelAndView("errorView.jsp");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the bloc that add data to model when RegisteredUsers is not null

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/validLogin")
 public ModelAndView validLogin(@RequestParam(name = "email", defaultValue = "retryEmail") String email, @RequestParam(name = "password", defaultValue = 
 "retryPass") String password) {
 ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
 RegisteredUsers s1=docDao.findByEmailAndPassword(email,password);            
 System.out.println("email id: " + email+" password : " + password);
 if(s1 != null) {
 System.out.println("Value exists..");
 mv.addObject("email",email);
 mv.addObject("password",password);
 mv.addObject(s1);
 mv.setViewName("validLogin.jsp");
 return mv;
 }else {
return new ModelAndView("errorView.jsp");
}
}
```

Comment: now it's working as it supposed to be..Thanks a Lot!